# Дать ответ http

Tags: golang, http

Стоит задача посчитать числа фиббоначи и передать их в ответ на http запрос пользователя.

Я сделал реализацию подсчета, принятия аргументов от пользователя, но мне в голову не приходит как передать ответ по http обратно пользователю.

Мне только приходит в голову Показать пользователю html с ответом, но это не подходит, нужно именно по http передать ответ тому кто вводил данные в форму.

Вот основная логика

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

//непосредственно функция подсчета фибоначи.
func fib(n int) uint {
    if n < 2 {
        return 1
    }
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
}

type fibfunc func(int) uint

//заполнение слайса результирующими значениями
func returningFib(fib fibfunc, a, b int) []uint {
    slc := make([]uint, 0, b-a+1)
    for i := a; i < b; i++ {
        slc = append(slc, fib(i))
    }
    return slc
}

//получает от ползователя диапазон в котором нужно рассчитать фиббоначи
func GettingAB(r *http.Request) (int, int) {
    r.ParseForm()
    a := r.FormValue("a")
    b := r.FormValue("b")
    aconv, _ := strconv.Atoi(a)
    bconv, _ := strconv.Atoi(b)
    return aconv, bconv
}

//делает вычсиление фиббоначи по заданному диапазону чисел и возвращает слайс с результатом.
//Этот слайс и нужно передать обратно тому кто ввел 'a' и 'b' в формы
func Doing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []uint {
    a, b := GettingAB(r)
    return returningFib(fib, a, b)
}

//получаю http заголовки пользователя который ввел в форму дынные.
//Остается по этим данным сделать обратный POST запрос пользователю со сайсом из Doing(w, r)
func GetUserHeader(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) http.Header {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        return r.Header
    }
    return nil
}

func ReturnFibToUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //...здесь можно написать пример решения. Можно не для копипаста, а приблизительно)
}

//главный хэндлер, описывает как реагировать на запросы.
func HandlerMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        ReturnFibToUser(w, r) //вызов функции которая еще не написана
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./test.html")
    case "GET":
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./test.html")
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HandlerMain)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

Вот форма ввода аргументов от пользователя (test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="a">
        <input type="text" name="b">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Признателен за внимание!)

Comment: `ReturnFibToUser` - отобразит данные, но потом `http.ServeFile` - стирает все. разве не так?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor да, так. Это я просто не убрал случайно. )

Comment: `Мне только приходит в голову Показать пользователю html с ответом, но это не подходит, нужно именно по http передать ответ тому кто вводил данные в форму.`  это не верно. вы на каждый запрос отвечаете своим индивидуальным ответом. это может быть как html, так и другие ответы. 
надо просто в шаблоне добавить отображение данных и все.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor То есть html будет телом ответа так?
request.Body.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor
Вот дословно задача
"Сервис должен отвечать на запросы и возвращать ответ. В ответе должны быть перечислены все числа, последовательности Фибоначчи с порядковыми номерами от x до y."

Comment: мне кажется, что от вас хотят простой rest сервис, который примет запрос POST со входными параметрами и даст ответ в виде JSON со списком чисел

Comment: @Думаю так и есть. Получается этот код что есть не подходит? Как же json передать обратно при запросе?
Сечас я делаю в терминале curl -d "a=5&b=12"  192.168.1.109:8181/ и получаю темплейт с последовательностью. Но  про json в задании ничего нет.

Comment: вам надо не html строить. а JSON запрос-ответ. то есть обычный rest запрос. тело запроса будет что угодно. например, JSON. 
`curl --data "{"a":  50, "b": 20 }" localhost:8080/my_endpoint_name`, а в ответ получите что-то `{[ 1, 2,  3, 5, ...]}` но я не уверен. надо уточнить что именно от вас хотят

Comment: @дада, есть в дополнительных задачах речь про rest
Дословно
"Требуется реализовать два протокола: HTTP REST и GRPC"

Comment: ну вот) значит делайте так

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Получается нужно сделать unmarshall даных от пользователя и потом уже обработать эти данные. А каким образом дать ответ если не html? Вот я обработаю a и b из json. А как дать ответ в виде фиббоначи?

Comment: лучше приложу ссылку https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin

Comment: @SeniorPomidor можете глянуть сделал ли я rest? или снова не то?

Comment: будет лучше если лишее удалить с вопроса. а то когда новый человек будет читать, то даже не поймет в чем была причина и почему ответ принят. 
а так вроде все верно. но лучше удалить последний апдейт

Answer (score 1):

я бы использовал темплейты. если есть вводимые данные, то нужно отобразить, если нет, то ничего не нужно.

p.s. не забудьде добавить проверку перед тем, как создавать массив

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

// непосредственно функция подсчета фибоначи.
func fib(n int) uint {
    if n < 2 {
        return 1
    }
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
}

type fibfunc func(int) uint

// заполнение слайса результирующими значениями
func returningFib(fib fibfunc, a, b int) []uint {
    slc := make([]uint, 0, b-a+1)
    for i := a; i < b; i++ {
        slc = append(slc, fib(i))
    }
    return slc
}

// получает от ползователя диапазон в котором нужно рассчитать фиббоначи
func GettingAB(r *http.Request) (int, int) {
    r.ParseForm()
    a := r.FormValue("a")
    b := r.FormValue("b")
    aconv, _ := strconv.Atoi(a)
    bconv, _ := strconv.Atoi(b)
    return aconv, bconv
}

// делает вычсиление фиббоначи по заданному диапазону чисел и возвращает слайс с результатом.
// Этот слайс и нужно передать обратно тому кто ввел 'a' и 'b' в формы
func Doing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []uint {
    a, b := GettingAB(r)
    return returningFib(fib, a, b)
}

// получаю http заголовки пользователя который ввел в форму дынные.
// Остается по этим данным сделать обратный POST запрос пользователю со сайсом из Doing(w, r)
func GetUserHeader(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) http.Header {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        return r.Header
    }
    return nil
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data interface{}) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("/path/to/html.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    tmplContext := struct {
        Data interface{}
    }{data}

    err = t.Execute(w, tmplContext)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

// главный хэндлер, описывает как реагировать на запросы.
func HandlerMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        dd := Doing(w, r)
        renderTemplate(w,r, dd)
    case "GET":
        renderTemplate(w,r, nil)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HandlerMain)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{ if not .}}
{{ else }}
    {{range .Data}}
<div> {{.}}</div>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавил свой код к которому я пришел. После UPD в моем вопросе. Если не сложно не могли бы глянуть?

Comment: Ан нет. Работает. Через параметра a и b передал и получил в ответ последовательность))

Comment: Ваш ответ верный но я по своему все же сделал. Спсибо))

Answer (score 0):

Сделал как я считаю rest версию решения задачи. Если это неверно, пожалуйста напишите мне))

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Result struct {
    Res []uint `json:"res"`
}

type Values struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
    B int `json:"b"`
}

func fib(n int) uint {
    if n < 2 {
        return 1
    }
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}

type fibfunc func(int) uint

func ReturnSlce(fib fibfunc, a, b int) []uint {
    slc := make([]uint, 0, b-a+1)
    for i := a; i < b; i++ {
        slc = append(slc, fib(i))
    }
    return slc
}

func postValues(c *gin.Context) {
    var vals Values
    c.BindJSON(&vals)
    var res = Result{
        Res: ReturnSlce(fib, vals.A, vals.B),
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, res)
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/test", postValues)
    router.Run(":8181")
}
```

Это стало возможным благодаря [SeniorPomidor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209435/senior-pomidor) и [руководству](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/web-service-gin) на оф сайте Golang по данному вопросу

UPD:
Сделал вычисление фибоначи итеративным. Рекурсия долгая. В итоге функция fib изменилась и стала такой:

```
func fib(n int) uint {
    var a, b uint = 1, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        a, b = b, a+b
    }
    return a
}
```